# I have given something to someone in past but the exact time I do not remember

Tags: past-tense, perfect-constructions

> I **had given** my library card to someone in class but I don't seem to recall to whom **I gave** my card. According to information that **I received** from the library, someone has used it to issue x-book and the date to submit the book was 1st Feb.

or

> I **had given** my library card to someone in class but I don't seem to recall to whom **I have given** my card. According to information that **I have received** from the library, someone has used it to issue x-book and the date to submit the book was 1st Feb.

What I want to say is that I gave my library card to someone in past-time (but the exact past time I do not remember) and I don't seem to recall to whom I gave my card.

What does the past perfect tense in the first line mean ?

Comment: I had given my library card to someone in class, but I don't seem to recall to whom I had given [it]. According to information that I have received from the library, someone has used it to borrow X Book and the date to return it had been February first.

Answer (score 2):

Present perfect **I have given** is a good way to express and action that was completed in the past but has a lasting consequence. It is ideal for this situation because the other person **still has your card**. Likewise, **has used** emphasises that the book is still issued.

For the other three verbs, simple past is fine, as there is no particular need to emphasise the lasting consequence:

I **have given** my library card to someone in class but i don't seem to recall to whom I **gave** my card... According to information that I **received** from library, someone **has used** it to issue x-book and the date to submit the book **was** 1st Feb.

**to whom I gave my card** is grammatically correct, but very formal: most people would say, and many would write **who I gave my card to**. Also, you should probably use **return** rather than **submit**. You submit something for publication: you return something that somebody lent to you.

You would not use past perfect unless you want to describe what happened before some reference event in the past. For example, if you were reminiscing with a friend about your university days and you say:

> Do you remember when I got that letter from the library about an overdue book? *that's the reference event* 
>   I **had given** my library card to someone... *that's what happened before the reference event, so we use past perfect*

Comment: and what if the situation has become past now .
Imagine i want to tell this story to someone after 5 years from now . what tenses should i use . would the sentence be like .



when i was in 3rd year of my college. something happend......

I had given my library card to someone in class but i did not seem to recall to whom I had given my card... According to information that I had received from library, someone had used it to issue x-book and the date to submit the book was 1st Feb.

Comment: Personally, I would not use present perfect since the action of giving the card has also ended, but I could maybe understand your argument for it.

Comment: and also **For the other two verbs, ..the lasting consequence**

if i use present perfect there also would that make the sentence wrong.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang, the situation is analogous to "I have booked some tickets for next week's show" (booking still in force) rather than "I booked some tickets for next week's show", which one might only say if something had since come up that forced you to cancel the booking.

Comment: @Toxic, you could change **gave->have given** and **received->have received** but not **was->has been**. But generally you want to use the simplest tense that does the job.

Comment: Hmmm, @JavaLatte, I'm not sure if I agree with your sentiment that one would only use past tense if the booking were not in force anymore, but as I had said, I could understand your argument for it.

Answer (score 0):

> I **had given** my library card to her, and she later **used** it to borrow a book.

The explanation above explains a sequence of events that happened in the past. You are explaining what happened back then.

> I **gave** my library card to her, and she **has used** it to borrow a book.

There, you are explaining a situation that is current now: the book is not in the library; she has it *now*. She borrowed it from the library recently, using your card.

Your not being able to remember who you gave your card to is a "red herring". It has nothing to do with the choice of tenses.

Comment: so the correct form is simple past ? and the sentence then would be like :

I gave my library card to someone in class but i don't seem to recall to whom I gave my card... According to information that I have received from library, someone has used it to issue x-book and the date to submit the book was 1st Feb.

Comment: If you're referring to a book that is overdue **now**, this would be clearest: "you **gave** the card to someone (you cannot remember who it was) and they **have used** it to borrow a book, which is now overdue, the duedate being Feb 1st"

Comment: **issue** is not the right verb, you mean **borrow**. And **submit** is also not correct; the verb there would be **return**.